# How to replay a League of Legends match?

Tags: league-of-legends

I have seen some videos (on YouTube) of LoL games where the commentator analyze the match and he's able to move freely through the map.

Are these video made from a streaming live game or are they made by replaying something saved locally on PC?

How to save and replay a match?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can record games with http://www.leaguereplays.com/

The LRF file just plays with the game itself.
You can browse the match, but you don't have information your character did not saw during the game.

Besides those limitations, I think it is possible to record video of this with comments.

Comment: Hey, thanks a lot, it's really fantastic! I tried yesterday to record and replay a match and it worked well. The only drawback is that I didn't found a way to jump to a specific point in time.

Comment: It's not a perfect tool indeed. But a good start. Maybe they'll try to do better I do not follow the devs stages.

Comment: Just a note: recent versions of LoLReplay provide the option to simultaneously record a spectator view of your games which functions exactly as an actual spectator view would.  (Of course, this means you won't be able to see chat.)

Answer (score 9):

**This feature has been added as of season 7.** Here is the announcement from Riot:

> [**That brings us to where we are today. We are ready to announce that Replays are coming to the League client update this pre-season.**](http://na.leagueoflegends.com/en/news/client/client-features/road-pre-season-replays-horizon)
>
> [image]
>
> Here’s how it works:
>
> - Download your replay from the End of Game Screen or Match History.
> - Watch Replays from the current patch using our new Replay Mode, with the functionality you’re used to from Spectator Mode.
> - Find cool moments using the new Annotated Timeline, which marks major events like kills, takedowns of towers and inhibitors, and
>     dragon/baron kills.
> - Capture video clips of your in-game moments (“Highlights”) using built-in recording functionality.
> - These Highlights will be stored on your hard drive (C:\MyDocuments\LeagueofLegends\Highlights) as a .webm video file.
>     These files can be viewed by opening them in any browser that supports
>     HTML5, and shared to social media alongside your cat gifs.
>
> With all of those pieces put together, you’ll be able to quickly
>   capture, save, and share your favorite moments on video to share
>   whenever you want.

**Note that the full-game recordings (.rofl) give you all the features of spectator mode, so you can see more than your own team's perspective.**

---

I have the Alpha Client, so here's a screenshot from my match history:

[image: Match history showing replay buttons]

- I have not downloaded a replay of the first match, so it shows the download button
- I have downloaded a replay of the second match, so it shows the replay button.

**Replays currently expire after three days.** Once a replay has expired, the button will be grayed out.

Answer (score 4):

**Edit: the previous version of this answer is out of date.**

Revisiting this post on 2017-04-05 it seems like replay.gg no longer works. I know of people who use https://www.plays.tv/ which might be worth checking out.

**Original post:**

http://replay.gg/

You have to do some initial setup but after that it works automatically, sending you an email after each game. The email contains instructions on how to view the replay, which is in spectator format. You view the game using the LoL client, which means you do all the things you can when you spectate normally e.g. rewind, see the whole map, see every player's build.

Comment: Nice one. Is this new?

Comment: If you want a solution local to your machine, I recommend [League Summoner Information](http://www.leaguelsi.com/). It has other tools as well, but the replays are what I use it for.

Comment: Also, this question could definitely use an updated answer. Quite a bit has changed in the last four years.

Comment: Yeah I came across this question from a google search, so I believe it's worth putting a newer answer.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, League of Legends supports no replay functionalities natively. There are some external apps though, please check:
http://www.leagueoflegends.com/board/showthread.php?t=504515

Answer (score 0):

One of the more popular gameplay recorders for recording LoL matches is the [Plays.tv client](http://plays.tv/download).  It automatically starts recording whenever you jump in the game and it bookmarks every key moments (KDA, Baron kill, Dragon kill, etc) from the game for you so that you can easily find those moments after your match.

Answer (score -1):

The videos you must have seen, are most likely official LoL streams, for events like the W.C.G or other tournaments. Those matches are ran on a special server (and by special I mean not the ordinary we usually login to play); did you notice on such matches, that the commentator had the whole map revealed? or did you notice that the commentator was actually a 6th member of one of the teams?

*Phreak* is usually the commentator of these matches, the following are some archived streams from some of the Tourneys, were you can see what I have explained here:
[IEM WC LoL: Grand Final](http://www.own3d.tv/game/League%20of%20Legends#/watch/82334)
[National ESL League](http://www.own3d.tv/game/League%20of%20Legends#/watch/99790)
Notice specially on the latter how on the champion selection there are 6 players instead of the routinary 5, 2 of the extra players are MOD summoners, that have a summoner spell (check while the game loads, the summoner spell the 6th player has!) that reveals the map and allows them to move freely through the map.

Now, on your second question, there is no such thing as replays implemented on the game for now, people have been requesting it along with the new map Magma Chamber; I think it should be finally implemented with the launching of Season II.

Comment: Yes, I noticed that commentator can see the whole map. In the specific case I was looking at this Roam Alistar video: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Vybqg7_ei8k

Comment: @Drake the video you posted is just a fan video, whose commentator is Teemo if Im not wrong? Also notice they recorded the game using a 3rd Party Tool and not an official recorder. Re-check the links I gave to see the powers of a Live mod on a game, you are able to see the whole map but REVEALED, no fog of war :)

Answer (score -1):

As far as I know, there are two ways to record a game.

1. You can record your point of view by using **video recorders** (helps you to explicitly know where you were looking at, where did you point your mouse, etc.), such as [***Open Broadcaster Software (OBS)***](https://obsproject.com/) which is free or [***Fraps***](http://www.fraps.com/) (not recommended for editing purposes though). The downside is that you need a computer with better specs to do the recording while playing, without affecting game's performance negatively (to not run it slower).
2. Record the entire game as a demo to play within the client. There are many options, I'd opt either for:

   - [***replay.gg***](http://replay.gg/). Unlike any other, it's an online recorder (this means you doesn't need to install it). Just follow the steps and the system does it for you. 
     **UPDATE (December 18 2015)**: It is failing a lot, so for now I'd opt for the local recorders...
   - [***League Summoner Information (LSI)***](http://www.leaguelsi.com/) but has way too much tools and personally a bit of an annoyance (but at least it works).
   - [***SkinSpotlights Replays***](http://www.skinspotlights.com/p/skinspotlights-replays.html) is working really good for me. Very lite and efficient.

Not necesarily has to be one of two, you can do both. The first one does cost your fps in-game whereas the second one doesn't.

Comment: Then there's [Lol Replays](http://www.leaguereplays.com/), which is often bugged for many players (heck, even the website doesn't respond most of the time), rendering it personally useless, and the same thing applies to [BaronReplays](https://ahri.tw/en/), but hey, maybe it's just me and my gaming machine, lol!