# LoL Replays not running on mid end PC (PH SERVER)

Tags: league-of-legends

So I Installed LoL replays. followed the instructions, and the started a game VS AI. My first experience was, it was very lag, but its AI so I went through it. After finishing the game, I tried to extract the replay, but I cant find one. After checking the LoL replay servers, I can't seem to find one which indicates PH server, Is this the reason why I cant use LoL replay?

Sorry, Pertaining to the MID END PC, My computer specs are

Intel Core i5, 1GB 256mb VC, 1pc 8GB RAM, GigaBit MB.

Mid end because I think my pc is good, but not that good.

Comment: I thought LoL Replay didn't work anymore? Also what is the ph server? Is that garena?

Comment: Or are you talking about LoL Replay 2?

Comment: I used LoLreplay only, and you're the only guy that told me it doesnt work anymore, maybe that's the reason why. And yes, it is garena.

Comment: Try LoL Replay 2, but the problem may just be that you're playing on garena instead of an official server. I'm not sure.

Comment: @Aequitas LoL Replay is broken since the discovery of fire

Comment: Look for Baron Replay. Was still working last I checked. Plus, I don't think you'll need it for very long, Riot announced their embedded replay system for S7

Comment: [Related](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/20263/how-to-replay-a-league-of-legends-match)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To my knowledge, LoLReplay does not keep the saves from bot games. You need to play against real players in order to save the replay.

Luckily, there is a new replay system in the new client, just check it out, it works pretty good.