# League of Legends Client Beta - Where do recordings save to?

Tags: league-of-legends

I have recorded a segment from a recent game from the new beta client replay feature. Where do those recordings get saved?

Client Beta Version: 6.22.3353521.3353110

Comment: A dupe from 5 years ago ? No, the OP was asking about the specific record feature that appeared on the beta client. The question is legit and doesn't mean at all "_How can I record my League games (with a third party software) ?_"

Comment: @Ksyqo You realize that those answers in that post are all outdated except for mine, right? The information the OP wants here is essentially contained in my answer. http://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/290083/115693

Comment: @mbomb007 Agreed. But the post is *outdated* and needed a new question. This is *not* a dupe because the question is not the same at all, even though your answer matches both of them.

Comment: @Ksyqo The post isn't outdated. Only some of the answers are outdated. People just need to view the post and vote some answers up or down.

Comment: @mbomb007 That's debatable. I get your point though. I [asked](http://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/12132/mark-as-duplicate-because-an-answer-matches-2-different-questions) some clarifications about this on Arqade Meta.

Comment: Actually I understood question differently. "Where do recordings save to?" - where on disk they go. Im alone? Also, "How to replay a League of Legends match?" is more valid, just need some update if required.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

According to this [official post](http://boards.na.leagueoflegends.com/en/c/developer-corner/2JWmR6sF-replays-are-live-in-the-new-client-faq-pro-tips), you have the possibility to download the replay (`.rofl` file) by clicking on the <kbd>Download</kbd> button at the top right corner of the end game screen. Then you can watch your replay in the client.

You can also record **highlights** from your recorded game, by pressing on the <kbd>Record</kbd> button. It will record a *fraction* of your game (an epic flash outplay, your first pentakill, a game-breaker backdoor...) and will be saved at :

`C:\Users\<Insert Your User Name Here>\Documents\LeagueofLegends\Highlights`

in the `.webm` format.

> .webm’s are an open sourced video format that plays nicely with HTML5. That means you can drag and drop those video files into Firefox & Chrome and they’ll automatically play. Additionally, we’ve found that VLC media player http://www.videolan.org/vlc/index.html works well for playback.

Comment: They really made it so the extension of the file is .rofl ? ROFL.

Comment: Agreed. Riot game employees seem to have a great time

Comment: @Karlyr, rofl is valid extension for lol

Comment: @Sanctus Yes... I know... It's just that the programmer chose the letters rofl for the extension... That's what is funny...

Comment: What about on Mac?